# Pass List<String> to Jquery in Play Framework

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.2.6 and need to get `List<String>` or `String[]` from controller to my jQuery Ajax call.

My controller looks like:

```
 public static Result list(){
    List<String> cname = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] arr= new String[]{"abc","abc2"};
    return ok(index.render(arr));
}
```

Code for Index method:

```
public static Result index(){
    String[] arr= new String[]{"abc","abc2"};
    return ok(index.render(arr));
}
```

and my jQuery function looks like:

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    ajaxCall(); 
}); 
var ajaxCall = function() {
    var ajaxCallBack = {
        success : onSuccess,
        error : onError
    }

    jsRoutes.controllers.Application.list().ajax(ajaxCallBack);
};

var  onSuccess = function(data) {
    console.log(data)
} 
var onError = function(error) {
    alert(error);
}
</script>
```

This script is in index.scala.html file and routes are:

```
GET     /                   controllers.Application.index()
POST    /                   controllers.Application.list()
GET     /javascriptRoutes   controllers.JavascriptRoute.javascriptRoutes
```

Ajax response works perfect for String type e.g. if I say

```
return ok("This is string");
```

Then I can see it in Ajax response but can't figure out why array or list throws below error:

> Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
>   cannot find symbol [symbol: method ok(java.lang.String[])] [location: class controllers.Application]

Just to mention I defined this method as POST in routes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the error is thrown for a GET call which is associated to the index() method, while the code you posted is related to the list() method (which is associated to a POST call). Is it correct?

Comment: so, could you post the code of the index() method, which is the one that throws the error?

Comment: Edited the question !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are responding with a rendered index template and the exception is being thrown when trying to render that template. What you want to do is respond with the JSON data.

```
public static Result list(){
    String[] arr= new String[]{"abc","abc2"};
    return ok(Json.toJson(arr));
}
```

tested it locally in my browser with the following code

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/",
    dataType: "script",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    }
});
```

EDIT:
So you could do something like this:

```
List<ObjectNode> objectNodes = new ArrayList<>();
ObjectNode objectNode = Json.newObject();
objectNode.put("Latitude", "13.679389");
objectNode.put("Longitude", "-13.679389");
objectNodes.add(objectNode);
// create loop to add more nodes
return ok(Json.toJson(objectNodes));`
```

And in your ajax response you will now have a list of nodes with Longitude and Latitude values

Comment: I want to pass the List or array which has Latitude and Longitude in it and then I will iterate it in index.html to build the google map object !

Comment: I added to the answer. You would then iterate over the response data and pull the longitude and latitude values from each node. Let me know if you're still having trouble